# Calculating annual percentage yield (apy) value for Uniswap pairs

Tags: javascript, external-api, uniswap

I wants to calculate annual percentage yield for a token pair listed on uniswap like [this](https://info.uniswap.org/pair/0xa478c2975ab1ea89e8196811f51a7b7ade33eb11). Is there any API which I can use to retrieve the value? How can it be directly calculated?

Comment: It depends on the trading volume (total conversion amount) during an entire year. So there is no single accurate answer to your question.

Comment: Are you looking for historical price data? Specific to uniswap or in general.

Comment: Yes and calculating apy