# How to calculate annual percentage yield on an AMM?

Tags: defi, liquidity-provider, amm

A related question has been asked [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/90016/86303) but a satisfactory answer has not been provided. I understand that APY for x*y=k AMMs is a function of average volume(`V`), liquidity provided by LP(`l`), fee(`f`) and total liquidity provided by all LPs(`L`) that has a relationship that approximates: `APY ~ ((l/L)*V*f)/l` (1) which can be reduced to `APY ~ (V*f)/L` (2).

So for example if `f=1%`, `V=$100m/year`, `(l/L)=1%`, `l=$100k`, then:

> APY = ((1%)*($100m/year)*1%)/$100k = 10% APY

Or using (2):

> APY = (($100m/year)*1%)/$10m = 10% APY

Would this an accurate way of calculating APY for arbitrary token pairs?